# insert html between two elements with mouse move event in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some light in this way.

I'm trying to add html with mouseover event , I want that when the user put the mouse over an element, appear a blue line to tell where is the point where it will insert the html, of course I'm thinking that when the user put cursor over an element l will have to calculate distance between element and closer to the cursor, to thereby add the line and the html before or after an element.

The help I need is that I've lost a bit, not if I am following the steps correctly.

I put the code that I have so far.

```
function distPoint(current,compare){

        return -(current - compare);

    }
    iframe.find("*").not("html,body").mousemove(function(e) {

        var el             = $(this);
        var currentElement = $(e.target);
        var y              = e.originalEvent.clientY;
        var yCurrent       = currentElement.offset().top;
        var nextELement    = currentElement.next();
        var prevElement    = currentElement.prev();
        var yNextELement   = nextELement.offset().top;
        var yPrevELement   = prevElement.offset().top;
        var distPrevY      = distPoint(y,yPrevELement);
        var distNextY      = distPoint(y,yNextELement);

        if(distPrevY > distNextY){
            elementInsert=nextELement;
            boder="border-top";
        }else{
            elementInsert=prevElement;
            boder="border-bottom";
        }

        console.log('yMouse: ' + y);
        console.log('yPrevELement: ' + yPrevELement + 'distPrevY: ' + distPrevY);
        console.log('yNextELement: ' + yNextELement + 'distNextY: ' + distNextY);

    });
```

UPDATE:
I'm having trouble getting the previous and next elemets, not because it gives me the value of Y, they know the way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this .live() function of jquery

```
var aSrc = /facebook|twitter/; //to match the particular iframe in document

$('iframe').live('mouseover', 
  function () {
      if(aSrc.test($(this).attr('src'))){ //if its same iframe u expecting
             alert('Found it!'); //Your logic here
      }
  }  
);​
```

**Edit the content of iframe from parent**

```
var element=  $('#myiframe').contents().hasClass('.elem1').after($('<div class="new"></div>'));
```

Comment: I do not look for anything, I just want to add html between two elements within an iframe.

Comment: you want to edit the content of iframe from parent page correct?

Comment: Between two elements of the iframe I want to add a piece of code. I think the title says it clearly. or not? detecting element on the mouse and insert before or after, according to this closer.

Comment: try this code $('#myiframe').contents().hasClass('.elem1').after($('<div class="new"></div>'))